# Ruby `require` doesn't find my file in rails lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load, require

I'm trying to load a file from my rails 'lib' dir, but I get the error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- lib/ss.rb
```

This is odd because in the console:

```
File::exist? 'lib/ss.rb' # => true
load 'lib/ss.rb' # => true
require 'lib/ss.rb' # => LoadError
```

What's more, this file should be auto-loading on start because in my application.rb file, I uncommented the line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Can anyone give me insight?

Comment: Have you enabled threadsafe! ?

Comment: I have not. How might that be involved?

Comment: in threadsafe mode, autoloading is disabled. Not related if you havent'  enabled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include lib and .rb

```
require "ssl"
```